# New column with ordered numbers after select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named Person like:

```
Name | Surname | Age
--------------------
Foo  | Bar     | 23
Faz  | Caz     | 17
Cas  | Zas     | 26
```

Is there any 'easy' way (function or something) to create new auto increment column while using select query? But just for result, no real change in database.
For instance if I use:

```
SELECT 'test' as new_col, Name, Surname, Age FROM Person;
```

I would get result with new column `new_col`. I want exchange this `'test'` with raising by 1 number for each column: 1, 2, 3 etc.

Expected result:

```
new_col | Name | Surname | Age
------------------------------
   1    | Foo  | Bar     | 23
   2    | Faz  | Caz     | 17
   3    | Cas  | Zas     | 26
```

I know I can create function or procedure with variables but maybe there is easier way that I am not aware of?

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) as new_col, 'test' as new_col, Name, Surname, Age
FROM Person;
```

Or in older versions of MySQL:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as new_col, 'test' as new_col, p.Name, p.Surname, p.Age
FROM Person p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
```

Comment: This is it! Soo easy, feeling ashamed now that I couldn't find it. Thank you very much ;)